# Is pageflip UI possible in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, css

[Experimental Page Layout Inspired by Flipboard](http://tympanus.net/Development/FlipboardPageLayout/?page=0) shows a flipping page where the page is flipped like a book page.

Is it possible to do that in IE, with HTML, CSS3 and JavaScript, without Flash?

Comment: Do you really think CSS3 is possible in IE? At least, give us a version number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be possible in IE 10.

The website uses the CSS 3 property `-webkit-transform`.

The new IE 10 (only available for Windows 7* and 8) **supports** `transform` natively without any vendor prefix!


IE 9 only supports 2D transforms including `-ms` prefix.

<sup>*) Only some beta testers were allowed to download IE 10 for Windows 7.</sup>

Comment: Actually, IE10 supports transform without the prefix – it's only needed in IE9, but of course, IE9 doesn't have 3d transforms.

Comment: You're right. I only use `-ms-transform` because of IE 9 support for Windows Vista users.

Comment: Is IE10 available for windows7? I thought it was 8 only

Comment: Microsoft offered some beta testers to download IE 10 for Windows 7. I think it'll be released in October when Windows 8 comes out.

Comment: Ah ok, I assumed it was 8 only as the current link on MSDN just refers you to the Win8 installer!